# Changing search terms results a 403 - dsIDXpress Pro plugin

Tags: search, errors

I face an issue with the dsIDXpress Pro SEARCH.

Everytime I try to change the search terms the site gives a 403 error.
http://lagunaagent.com/idx/city/laguna-niguel/

From the error.log

```
[Wed Nov 07 10:51:30 2012] [warn] [client ******.46] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [****]/httpdocs/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:92) in [****]/wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress/client.php on line 407, referer: http://lagunaagent.com/idx/city/laguna-niguel/?idx-q-BedsMin=4&idx-q-ImprovedSqFtMin=2500&idx-q-PropertyTypes=545
```

`/dsidxpress/client.php` line 407 :

```
    // track the detail & result views, do this at the end in case something errors or w/e
    $views = intval(@$_COOKIE["dsidx-visitor-$action-views"]);
    setcookie("dsidx-visitor-$action-views", $views + 1, time()+60*60*24*30, '/');

    if (isset($seo_keywords) || isset($seo_description) || isset($seo_title)) {
        $dsidxpress_seo = new dsidxpress_seo($seo_title, $seo_description, $seo_keywords);
        add_action('wp_head', array($dsidxpress_seo, 'dsidxpress_head_action'));
        add_filter('wp_title', array($dsidxpress_seo, 'dsidxpress_title_filter'));
    }
```

Could you kindly point me if it's something server related???

I have already done some troubleshooting changing theme (twenty eleven) and switching on/off plugins with no results.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

It turned out that the Block Bad Queries (BBQ) plugin that I use simply blocked too much.

Marco